# What is the part between the eyebrow tail and above the eyelid called?

Tags: eye, anatomy, face, eyebrows

I need to know the anatomical name of the portion of the face between the eyebrow tail and the eyelid, as highlighted in red in the image below, as I need to refer to that particular area in writing succinctly and specifically and without any ambiguity or elaborate description.

Upon thorough digging, I have found out that the lacrimal glands (responsible for producing tears) are present underneath the skin of the highlighted part but I fear that lacrimal fossa (where the aforementioned gland is contained) is not the correct term for the highlighted portion as refers to the specific part of the human skull and definitely not the highlighted skin-area pertaining to facial anatomy.

Further brainstorming has got me to the conclusion that the best way to denote these areas in a succinct, unambiguous way without being too "technical" is through "left/right brow bone" but I feel that there is a better/more-specific term for this.

Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: Seems like using the lacrimal glands as a reference point would be concise and accurate.

Comment: This was answered on Biology.SE, where it was cross posted.